# jQuery .click() super simple but don't know what is going on

Tags: jquery

So I don't quite understand why my function is not working.

So I have a div that gets a class added to it using .addClass and then resizes to the width and height of the window.
When I try to make "close" the div to return the original size it the click function does not work.  I have included my code below. Any help is appreciated. I know this is probably a super simple solution.  For some reason it doesn't seem to be finding the element to remove the class of 'flip' and resize.

jQuery

```
 var windowHeight = $(window).height();
 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 $('.click').on("click", function () {
   $(this).addClass('flip').height(windowHeight).width(windowWidth);
 });
 // for the window resize
 $('#CloseThis').on("click", function () {
   //alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
   $('body .click').removeClass('flip').height(200).width(200);
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="click panel">
  <div class="front">
    <h2>Click or tap this circle!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <h2>Tap Again!</h2>
    <div id="CloseThis">Close this</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.CloseThis')` needs to be `$('#CloseThis')`

Comment: @Sushanth They must be, if the initial resize is working.

Comment: I actually made that change it still doesn't work.  I will reflect that in my post again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('.click').on("click", function () {
     $(this).addClass('flip').height(windowHeight).width(windowWidth);
});

$('#CloseThis').on("click", function (e) {
     $('.click').removeClass('flip').height(200).width(200);
     //  $(this).closest('.click') Multiple containers
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Added the `stopPropagation` so that the `.click` event is not fired when you click the div
`CloseThis` .

Also replaced the `$('body .click')` selector with `.closest()`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bgeK7/)**

Comment: What is the issue? Why could I not use the $(body .click) to remove the class?

Comment: Also .closest() helps the case when there are multiple containers with class .click on the page and when clicked you want to affect only contents in that particular block.. In your case you can simply replace it with $('.click')

Answer (score 0):

events traverse the dom, so when you click the #CloseThis the function fires but the event keeps moving up and hits youre .click function aswell. to keep this from happning we can instruct the browser not to pass the event on to parent elements, the Event argument contains this function:

```
$('.click').on("click", function () {
   $(this).addClass('flip').height(windowHeight).width(windowWidth);
});

$('.CloseThis').on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('body .click').removeClass('flip').height(200).width(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Similar to @Sushanth but without the .closest.

Comment: true and using closest are alot cleaner so you probly wanner use that, just wanted to give a small overview of what where going on :)